# How to call category collection on home page in magento 2?

Tags: category, collection, magento2

I want to show all the category on the left sidebar on home page. Please let me know how to get all the categories by collection, or there is another way to call all the category. please let me know

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [Adding layered navigation block to custom page](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/58/6549) and [applying layered navigation to CMS page filled with new products](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54326/applying-layered-navigation-to-cms-page-filled-with-new-products).  I think the answer in the second link will help you.

Comment: this is Magento 2 question, links related to Magento 1.x

Comment: the answer mention is in magento 1.x series , but i want to show categorys on home page (sidebar) in magento 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is open source extension for do that - you can use code and modify for your needs [Magento 2 Frontend : How to call category collection on home page](https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-home-categories) Explained in [blog post](http://ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page)

Comment: Awesome FireBear. Its work for me. thanks for giving such attention

Comment: How to show category images  I am using $category->getImageUrl();

but its not working

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php 
  $categoryHelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
  foreach($categoryHelper->getStoreCategories() as $category): 
?>
  <li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check below code:**

```
<?php
$objectManagerr = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                    $categoryFactory = $objectManagerr->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

                    $categories = $categoryFactory->create()                              
                                ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

foreach ($categories as $category):     
echo $category->getName();
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Btw, it's not recommended to use object manager directly for creating objects. Use DI instead.

Comment: Is there any way to get the products of current category like above? If any than please share..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DI in your class -
1. add property of AdminSession class to class 2. add including of the variable using dependensy injection:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
 */

protected $_storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface  $_storeManager
){
    $this->_storeManager = $_storeManager;
}
$store = 1;//store id
public function getCategories($store){
    $rootCategoryId = $this->_storeManager->getStore($store)
        ->getRootCategoryId();
    $collection = $this->_categoryCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('name','id')
        ->addIsActiveFilter(true)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))
        ->addLevelFilter(2);

    foreach ($collection as $category) {
        $categories[] = array(
            'id'=>$category->getId(),
            'name'=>$category->getName(),
        ); 
    }
    return $categories;
}
```